Add jar exclusion to OpenEJB excludeList from WAR or JAR at build time
I am deploying a WAR bundled with a library JAR-with-dependencies (aka fat jar).
I am excluding the jar from OpenEJB deployment because it has no beans that need to be deployed. It only contains library classes. I am using the TomEE conf/exclusion.list
I would like to be able to mark this jar as excluded from either the Web Descriptor web.xml or from inside the jar.
One facility for this is the org.apache.openejb.jee.AssemblyDescriptor excludeList (I think), but I don't know how to set this from the WAR or JAR.
I cannot and do not want to mark all the beans inside the jar.
Marking the exclusion in TomEE config is less than ideal because it has to be done on each server this WAR is deployed to.

Could you please explain your question a bit more. One clarification is, does the fat jar contain some beans and you don't want to deploy them or the jar does not contain any beans at all and you don't want it to be scanned during deploy time.

I don't want it to be scanned at all. Adding the jar to exclusion.list works for what I want, I just want to be able to do it in a self-contained manner
